# LoadLibrary fails in C++ Builder generated application

Tags: visual-c++, c++builder, loadlibrary

I am trying to load a DLL created with VC++ in an application created with C++Builder.

Using this code works fine, when only simple functions without dependencies should be called:

```
LoadLibraryEx(TEXT("wrapper.dll"), NULL, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES);
```

However, MSDN states that one should not use the `DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES` flag, and that with good reasons.

The preferred solution fails with `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND`:

```
LoadLibrary(TEXT("wrapper.dll"));
```

The DLL has a `DllMain()` entry point, and a VC++ compiled application can load it via `LoadLibrary` just fine.

Does anyone know how to load a DLL in a C++Builder application such that its references get resolved?

The DLL uses a static library which itself uses `Ws2_32.lib`.

Comment: Very hard to guess why you'd use DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES when you want "its references get resolved".  If normal loading fails with ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND then find out what dependent DLL is missing.  Get a diagnostic by enabling loader snaps or by using SysInternals' Process Monitor.

Comment: @HansPassant I hoped that presenting the Information that without resolving references the DLL could be load might be helpful..

Comment: @MatthiasLochbrunner: that fact points out that `wrapper.dll` has an external dependency. Whether you load the DLL in VC++ or C++Builder does not matter at all. The issue has nothing to do with the compiler, it is an OS search path issue. You need to figure out what that dependency is, and where `LoadLibrary()` is looking for it. There are tools available for that purpose. Then either 1) recompile the DLL to remove the dependency, or 2) make sure the dependency exists in your application deployment where the OS can find it.